# How to use :not in the selector for a dojo.on event name?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Since IE10 does not support pointer-events: none to prevent click on elements that have my .disabled class like this:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none !important;
    opacity: 0.4 !important;
    cursor: auto;
}
```

I figured I could work-around that by adding the class name to my click events selectors, like this:

```
on(node, ':not(.disabled):click', lang.hitch(this, this.myClickHandler));
```

Unfortunately it appears that the **:** in **:not** confuses dojo and it's not working.

If that's really the case, then how could I easily tell dojo to call the handler when (and only when) the node does not have the .disabled class? I'd prefer not to have to check this within the handler themselves, because that would mean we'd have to add code (the same code) within dozens of handlers.

Thanks for any suggestions

**Edit**: I found this workaround based on another thread where you can catch clicks on all div elements, and then stop the propagation if it has the disabled class. So it's a single point of maintenance for all button handlers.

```
                query('div').on('click', function(event){
                    if (domClass.contains(event.currentTarget, 'disabled')){ 
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo/on` uses `:` as the delimiter between selector and event name for event delegation, so `:not` is probably confusing it.  However, you can use `on.selector` to construct a custom event type yourself (which is normally what `on` does for you automatically when the second argument is a `selector:type` string):

`on(node, on.selector(':not(.disabled)', 'click'), ...);`

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yLqhok8t/

Comment: Thanks Ken. It does indeed seem to work with document.body in your jsfiddle, but I can't seem to make this work using a node like dom.byId('buttonId') though. The :not really seems to cause issues.

Comment: Can you show a specific example of what's not working?

Comment: Well for instance in your jsfiddle if you give the first button an id of button1 and then in your on() you replace document.body by dom.byId('button1'), it won't click even though the div doesn't have the .disabled class.

Comment: If by "first button" you meant "first div", then...that would be true, but then you have defeated the purpose by altering the example to listen directly on one of the components you were intending to delegate onto.  Delegation needs to be hooked up on a common ancestor to all of the elements intended for delegation.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for this. So I believe this answers my original question for :not. In my specific case I guess if I wanted a single point of maintenance I could use your example and call event.stopImmediatePropagation() in the handler to prevent the click on all disabled buttons in my application. Nice. A bit cleaner then the solution in my Edit.